# how to update database using room persistance library and livedata

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am trying to update my database using **Room persistence Library** and **Livedata**. I am very new to java, so, with the manual and various tutorial, I have setup the DAO, entity etc. But I am still struggling with how to actually add the data.

This is my database defination:

```
@Entity
public class PlaceSaved {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  private int id;
  private String place;
  private String lati;
  private String longi;


  public PlaceSaved(String place, String lati, String longi) {
    this.place = place;
    this.lati = lati;
    this.longi = longi;
  }

  public String getPlace() {
    return place;
  }
  public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
  }

  public String getLongi() {
    return longi;
  }
  public void setLongi(String longi) {
    this.longi = longi;
  }


  public String getLati() {
    return lati;
  }
  public void setLati(String lati) {
    this.lati = lati;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
public interface DatabaseInterface {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM placesaved")
  LiveData<List<PlaceSaved>> getAllItems();

  @Insert
  void insertAll(PlaceSaved... placeSaveds);
  @Delete
  void delete(PlaceSaved... placeSaveds);
  @Update
  void update(PlaceSaved... placeSaveds);
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>{
  private List<PlaceSaved> items;
  private View.OnClickListener ClickListener;

  public  PlacesAdapter(List<PlaceSaved> items){//}, View.OnClickListener ClickListener) {
        this.items = items;
        //this.ClickListener = ClickListener;
  }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.places_list_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PlaceSaved placeSaved = items.get(position);
        holder.itemTextView.setText(placeSaved.getPlace());
        holder.nameTextView.setText(placeSaved.getLati());
        holder.dateTextView.setText(placeSaved.getLongi());
/*        holder.dateTextView.setText(borrowModel.getBorrowDate().toLocaleString().substring(0, 11));
        holder.itemView.setTag(borrowModel);
        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void addItems(List<PlaceSaved> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView itemTextView;
        private TextView nameTextView;
        private TextView dateTextView;

        RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            itemTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            dateTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        }
    }
}
```

and the **ViewModel**

```
public class PlacesViewModel  extends AndroidViewModel {
  private final LiveData<List<PlaceSaved>> PlacedatabaseList;

  private PlaceDatabase appDatabase;

  public PlacesViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);

    appDatabase = PlaceDatabase.getDatabase(this.getApplication());

    PlacedatabaseList = appDatabase.PlacedatabaseInterface().getAllItems();
  }


  public LiveData<List<PlaceSaved>> getPlaceList() {
    return PlacedatabaseList;
  }

  public void deleteItem(PlaceSaved placeSaved) {
    new deleteAsyncTask(appDatabase).execute(placeSaved);
  }

  private static class deleteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<PlaceSaved, Void, Void> {

    private PlaceDatabase db;

    deleteAsyncTask(PlaceDatabase appDatabase) {
      db = appDatabase;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final PlaceSaved... params) {
      db.PlacedatabaseInterface().delete(params[0]);
      return null;
    }

  }
}
```

Now, I am trying to add an item to database with `OnClick` of a `fab` as:

```
public class PlacesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private PlacesViewModel viewModel;
  private PlacesAdapter placesAdapter;
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  FloatingActionButton fab, fab1, fab2, fab3;
  LinearLayout fabLayout1, fabLayout2, fabLayout3;
  boolean isFABOpen = false;
  View fabBGLayout;
  PlaceDatabase db;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.places_layout);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PlacesViewModel.class);

    Runnable r =new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        placesAdapter = new PlacesAdapter(new ArrayList<PlaceSaved>());//, this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(placesAdapter);
      }
    };

    Thread newThread = new Thread(r);
    newThread.start();

    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        //Dialog
/*
    Add location manually
*/
        AlertDialog.Builder placeLLDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlacesActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_add_dialog, null);

        placeLLDialog.setView(view);

        final EditText todo = view.findViewById(R.id.placeN);
        final EditText time = view.findViewById(R.id.placell);
        final EditText longi = view.findViewById(R.id.placell2);
        placeLLDialog.setTitle("Add Place with Latitude and Longitude")
          .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (!todo.getText().toString().equals("") &&
                  !time.getText().toString().equals("") &&
                  !longi.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Running", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  /* HERE I AM TRYING TO ADD THE DATA, WHICH IS NOT WORKING
                   final PlaceSaved placeSaved = new PlaceSaved(todo.getText().toString(),
                    time.getText().toString(), longi.getText().toString());
                    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      db.databaseInterface().insertAll(placeSaved);
                      items = db.databaseInterface().getAllItems();
                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          adapter = new PlacesAdapter(items, db, null);
                          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                          closeFABMenu();
                        }
                      });
                    }
                });*/
                }
              }
          })
          .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = placeLLDialog.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE  | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
      }
    });
```

since I am very new to java, I can't find out how to add the data to the database, which is inside `fab1.setOnClickListner`.

I will be grateful if someone kindly helps.

**UPDATE**
I forgot to add database itself, here it is:

```
@Database(entities = {PlaceSaved.class},version = 1)
public abstract class PlaceDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
  private static PlaceDatabase INSTANCE;
  public static PlaceDatabase getDatabase(Context context){
    if (INSTANCE == null){
      INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), PlaceDatabase.class,
          "places_db").build();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  public abstract DatabaseInterface PlacedatabaseInterface();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create Class AddBorrowViewModel**

```
public class AddBorrowViewModel extends AndroidViewModel
{
     private PlaceDatabase appDatabase;
    public AddBorrowViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        appDatabase = PlaceDatabase.getDatabase(this.getApplication());
    }

    public void addBorrow(PlaceSaved placedSaved)
    {
        new addAsyncTask(appDatabase).execute(placedSaved);

    }

    private class addAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask<PlaceSaved , Void, Void>
    {
        private PlaceDatabase appDatabase_;
        addAsyncTask(PlaceDatabase appDatabase)
        {
            appDatabase_ = appDatabase;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(PlaceSaved... placedSaved) {
            appDatabase_.itemAndPersonModel().addBorrow(placedSaved[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**add this variable in your PlacesActivity**

private AddBorrowViewModel addBorrowViewModel;

**in OnCreate add this**

```
addBorrowViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AddBorrowViewModel.class);
```

**in onClickListener Of alertDilaog after snackbar**

```
addBorrowViewModel.addBorrow(new PlaceSaved(
                            todo.getText().toString(),
                    time.getText().toString(), longi.getText().toString()
                    ));
```

**In your PlaceDatabase add**

```
public abstract Dao itemAndPersonModel();
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply, but this is giving error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.myapp.AddBorrowViewModel.addBorrow(com.example.myapp.PlaceSaved)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.myapp.PlacesActivity$3$1.onClick(PlacesActivity.java:99)

Comment: Also, in my post, I forgot to add the database. I have updated the main question.

Comment: add  this in your  database class public abstract Dao itemAndPersonModel();

Comment: Hi, sorry to sound silly, but in my original app, there is no itemAndPersonModel. can you kindly check and tell me what should I actually add?

Comment: Bro its abstract method. you only declare it database rest work is on you where to write definition for it

Comment: replace PlacedatabaseInterface() from your db with public abstract Dao itemAndPersonModel();

Comment: //  public abstract DatabaseInterface PlacedatabaseInterface();

  public abstract Dao PlacedatabaseInterface();

Like this is giving error:
Error:Dao class must be annotated with @Dao
Error:A DAO method can be annotated with only one of the following:Insert,Delete,Query,Update
Error:Abstract method in DAO must be annotated with interface android.arch.persistence.room.Query AND interface android.arch.persistence.room.Insert

Comment: DatabaseInterface is your dao class name..then use public abstract DatabaseInterface itemAndPersonModel();

Comment: hi, thanks, the app is working without error, but nothing is added to the database :(